# how to extract min and max date in consecutive line - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

How can I get min() and max() date from the table below?

```
id | sub_cat_id |   date
----------------------------
 2 |     1      | 1/2/2015
 2 |     1      | 2/2/2015
 2 |     1      | 3/2/2015
 2 |     1      | 6/2/2015
 2 |     1      | 7/2/2015
 2 |     3      | 1/2/2015
 2 |     3      | 30/3/2015
 2 |     3      | 31/3/2015
 2 |     3      | 1/4/2015
 2 |     3      | 2/4/2015
```

I would like to get result ->

```
id | sub_cat_id | start_date | end_date
----------------------------------------
 2 |     1      |  1/2/2015  | 3/2/2015
 2 |     1      |  6/2/2015  | 7/2/2015
 2 |     3      |  1/2/2015  | 1/2/2015
 2 |     3      |  30/3/2015 | 2/4/2015
```

Could you please advice me how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: This is indeed an interesting question. :) You should add whether the `date` within the groups are always increasing or there might be smaller values there (I assume there is a [clustered index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Clustered) somewhere, but it would be useful to state that too). I am afraid I have no good solution yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it using **ROW_NUMBER** analytic function. See [Find range of consecutive values in a sequence of numbers or dates](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/07/22/find-range-of-consecutive-values-in-a-sequence-of-numbers-or-dates/).

For example, let's say I have range of numbers with missing gaps:

```
SQL> WITH DATA(dates) AS(
  2  SELECT  DATE '2015-01-01' FROM dual UNION
  3  SELECT  DATE '2015-01-02' FROM dual UNION
  4  SELECT  DATE '2015-01-03' FROM dual UNION
  5  SELECT  DATE '2015-01-05' FROM dual UNION
  6  SELECT  DATE '2015-01-06' FROM dual UNION
  7  SELECT  DATE '2015-01-07' FROM dual UNION
  8  SELECT  DATE '2015-01-10' FROM dual UNION
  9  SELECT  DATE '2015-01-11' FROM dual UNION
 10  SELECT  DATE '2015-01-12' FROM dual UNION
 11  SELECT  DATE '2015-01-13' FROM dual UNION
 12  SELECT  DATE '2015-01-20' FROM dual
 13  )
 14  SELECT MIN(dates),
 15         MAX(dates)
 16  FROM
 17    ( SELECT dates, dates - row_number() OVER(ORDER BY dates) rn
 18      FROM DATA
 19    )
 20  GROUP BY rn
 21  ORDER BY rn;

MIN(DATES MAX(DATES
--------- ---------
01-JAN-15 03-JAN-15
05-JAN-15 07-JAN-15
10-JAN-15 13-JAN-15
20-JAN-15 20-JAN-15

SQL>
```

Comment: absolutely precise man ... thx so much :) this is exactly what I was looking for !!!

Comment: @Mr.P You're welcome. Please mark it as answered, would help others.